# Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript: add links to set date select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

Given a simple generic Rails form with a date_select (among other fields, I removed those in the code).

I'd love to add links to this form named Yesterday, Today, Tomorrow, ... , Next Week. A click on one of these links should set the date_select to the correct date (no submit of the form).

What is the best way to accomplish this in Rails 3 without too much Javascript hassle?

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
<% if @entry.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Datum" %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :datum %>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View

```
<div>
  Set date to: <span class="test"><%= Date.today.to_s %></span>
</div>
```

entries.js.coffee.erb

```
$ ->
  $('.test').bind 'click', ->
   text = $(this).text()
   $("#date_entry").val(text)
```